# Use BouncyCastle to verify Android KeyStore signed payload

Tags: c#, android, bouncycastle, keystore

I am trying to sign data using the KeyStore API from Android and verify the data in the server using BouncyCastle and C#.

My process for the verification is like this:

1. Generate a key pair on android
2. Send the public key to the server
3. Generate a challenge on the server
4. Sign the challenge on android using the private key
5. Verify the signed challenge on the server using the public key

I cannot get the verification to work properly. How can I get the verification to succeed? Is there a significant logic error?

#### This is the code I am using right now:

Generate the key pair using a `KeyPairGenerator`:

```
val generator: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")

val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("KEY_ALIAS",
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
)
    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
    .setKeySize(2048)
    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
    .build()

generator.initialize(parameterSpec)
generator.generateKeyPair()
```

Get the public key which is sent to the server:

```
val publicKeyBytes = keyStore.getCertificate("KEY_ALIAS").publicKey.encoded
val publicKey = Base64.encodeToString(publicKeyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

The server then generates a challenge payload which must be verified by the android app. The signing is done like this:

```
val challengeBytes = Base64.decode(challenge, Base64.DEFAULT)
val entry = keyStore.getEntry("KEY_ALIAS", null) as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry

val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS")

signature.initSign(entry.privateKey)
signature.update(challengeBytes)
val signedBytes = signature.sign()

val signedChallenge = Base64.encodeToString(signedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

This `signedChallenge` is then send to the server which will verify it using BouncyCastle in C#:

```
byte[] challengeBytes = // Original challenge
byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signedChallenge);

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities
    .GetSigner(
        SignerUtilities
            .GetObjectIdentifier("SHA256withRSA/PSS"));

var pKeyParams = (RsaKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));
signer.Init(false, pKeyParams);
signer.BlockUpdate(challengeBytes, 0, challengeBytes.Length);

isVerified = signer.VerifySignature(signedBytes);
```

#### Setup

Android: SDK 23+
The server is written in C# using the NuGet Package Portable.BouncyCastle Version 1.8.10

Comment: Your C# signer instantiation doesn't work on my machine, but `ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA/PSS");` does. With this, verification is successful (but under API 28 P). Try this.

Comment: When I create the instance using your method I get the same ISigner and verification does not work. However, I will look into it and try to get more information

Comment: You should debug on the C# side  what the values of `signer.contentDigest1`, `signer.contentDigest2`, `signer.sLen` and `signer.trailer` parameters are. The necessary values for compatibility with the Android code are `Sha256Digest`, `Sha256Digest`, `0x20` and `0xbc`. On my machine, they have the values `Sha1Digest`, `Sha1Digest`, `0x14` and `0xbc` when the signer is specified via the OID (according to the default values in RFC8017) and the correct values when the signer is specified directly via the algorithm.

Comment: The BC version I use is the same as yours (Portable.BouncyCastle, 1.8.10). However, standard BouncyCastle, v1.8.9 behaves identically. .NET is .NET Core 3.1/5.0 as well as .NET Framework 4.8. Which .NET version are you running?

Comment: I am using the latest .net 6.0 preview. 

However, the devil is in the details. I fixed the bug and it was how I loaded the original challenge. The original challenge was not loaded properly which lead to the signature validation failing. It is working now. 

Anyway, thanks for your help! It is very appreciated!

Comment: Just out of interest. Does it also run if the signer is generated via the OID (i.e. with `GetObjectIdentifier("SHA256withRSA/PSS")`) as in the posted code? This doesn't work on my machine, even with the 6.0 preview.

Comment: I tested it with the `GetObjectIdentifier("SHA256withRSA/PSS")` and it does *not* work. Indeed you have to use `ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA/PSS");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the instantiation of the `ISigner` in the C# code.

To make it work I had to get the signer like so:

```
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA/PSS");
```